# Node.js: is it possible to simulate an HTTP connection without external modules?

Tags: node.js

Let's assum I have a basic HTTP server, like the one on nodejs.org:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Is is it possible to simulate a connection to this server without using any npm module (socket.io, connect etc.) ?

The only way I have found by only using pure Node.js is by using [http.request](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) and running both the instances locally (both the server and the client simulator). However, I am unsure as to what drawbacks this has or if it is a valid option. Will this work if I try to simulate multiple connections, for example? Is network speed a bottleneck in this case? Is there a better/easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can make an HTTP request from within your computer, you won't be simulating it either, you'll be making an actual connection too. NodeJS's built in http module ships with a client as well as a server.

```
var http = require("http");
http.get("http://localhost:1337", function(resp){
   console.log("Request made!", resp);
});
```

Comment: By "simulating" in the original post, I meant simulating an external user which tries to connect to my server, not simulating an HTTP connection per se. However, would this work for multiple connections and still be a valid simulator of users connecting? (code-wise, connecting repeatedly in a `for` loop)

Comment: @cgf yes, it would. Making an HTTP connection _is_ how an external user connects to your server. You can make multiple connections in a loop - not that the client is limited by default by the number of connections it makes in parallel (this is solvable though, and not unlike other third party libraries who do this).

Comment: I also used this to simulate multiple connections to my server (connecting repeatedly in a `for` loop), but when these connections get aborted using the `.abort` method, the connections randomly get this error: `{ [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }`. Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks a lot :)